# Missing MFC CString operator==() overloads when using C++20 in VS2022 (17.0.6)

Tags: c++, mfc, c++20

**Update: This was fixed in VS2022 v17.2 Preview 1**

When I set my MFC project to use C++20, I'm getting errors when comparing string literals with `CString` instances.

For example:

```
CString s1 = _T("s1");
    
// this works
if (s1 == _T("s1")) {
  cout << "Match!"
}

// this generates a compiler error 
if (_T("s1") == s1) {
  cout << "Match!";
}
```

According to the `CStringT` documentation, there are a bunch of `==` overloads:

```
friend bool operator==(const CStringT& str1, const CStringT& str2) throw();
friend bool operator==(const CStringT& str1, PCXSTR psz2) throw();
friend bool operator==(const CStringT& str1, PCYSTR psz2) throw();
friend bool operator==(const CStringT& str1, XCHAR ch2) throw();
-> friend bool operator==(PCXSTR psz1, const CStringT& str2) throw();
friend bool operator==(PCYSTR psz1, const CStringT& str2,) throw();
friend bool operator==(XCHAR ch1, const CStringT& str2,) throw();
```

I marked the one I think it should be finding. However, it doesn't seem to even consider that overload:

```
error C2666: '==': 3 overloads have similar conversions
message : could be 'bool operator ==(const D2D1_RECT_U &,const D2D1_RECT_U &)'
message : or       'bool operator ==(const D2D1_SIZE_U &,const D2D1_SIZE_U &)'
message : or       'bool operator ==(const DEVPROPCOMPKEY &,const DEVPROPCOMPKEY &)'
message : or       'bool operator ==(const DEVPROPKEY &,const DEVPROPKEY &)'
message : or       'int operator ==(const PROPERTYKEY &,const PROPERTYKEY &)'
message : or       'bool operator ==(const GUID &,const GUID &)'
message : or       'bool ATL::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> &,const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
message : or       'bool ATL::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> &,const wchar_t *) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
message : or       'bool ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> &,const char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
message : or       'bool ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> &,wchar_t) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
message : or 'bool operator ==(const GUID &,const GUID &)' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
message : or 'bool ATL::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> &,const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> &) noexcept' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
message : or 'bool ATL::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> &,const wchar_t *) noexcept' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
message : or 'bool ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> &,const char *)' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
message : or 'bool ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>> &,wchar_t) noexcept' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
message : or 'int operator ==(const PROPERTYKEY &,const PROPERTYKEY &)' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
message : or 'bool operator ==(const DEVPROPKEY &,const DEVPROPKEY &)' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
message : or 'bool operator ==(const DEVPROPCOMPKEY &,const DEVPROPCOMPKEY &)' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
message : or 'bool operator ==(const D2D1_SIZE_U &,const D2D1_SIZE_U &)' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
message : or 'bool operator ==(const D2D1_RECT_U &,const D2D1_RECT_U &)' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
message : or       'built-in C++ operator==(const wchar_t [3], const wchar_t [3])'
message : or       'built-in C++ operator==(const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *)'
message : while trying to match the argument list '(const wchar_t [3], CString)'
```

So I went to the header file (`cstringt.h`) and found that a bunch of the `friend` functions, including the one I marked, are `#ifdef`'d out because `__cpp_lib_three_way_comparison` is `#define`'d.

Does the spaceship operator somehow make a bunch of those friend functions unnecessary? If so, what's the fix? I know I can change my comparison to `s1 == _T("s1")` but I like having a constant expression on the left in case I accidentally use `=` rather than `==`.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio is this about? Neither the question nor the error message indicate this.

Comment: Any version of Visual Studio equal to or greater than 16.11. As long as c++20 is the selected version of C++, I get this error. Versions prior to 16.11 did not support c++20.

Comment: @criddell I didn't check, but possibly is has been fixed in [Visual Studio 2022 17.0.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.0.5%20Visual%20Studio%202022%20version%2017.0.5). They claim they fixed a bug in ATL's CString comparisons under C++20 and C++Latest language .modes)

Comment: @Jabberwocky 17.0.5 is one of the versions I have installed and my code doesn't work in it either. But now you have me wondering if maybe this is a library bug and not something I'm doing incorrectly. If I don't find a solution in the next day or two, I'm going to submit this as a bug report.

Comment: After @Jabberwocky mentioned Microsoft's recent CString changes, I searched their support portal and found this: 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-comparison-operators-between-LPC/1614285
It looks like the same issue so hopefully they roll out a fix soon.

Comment: I believe this [was fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#issues-addressed-in-this-release) with release 16.11.10 of Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @IInspectable That seems to be the case. It's still broken in the 17.0.6. Hopefully they get that fixed soon as well. Both 16.11.10 and 17.0.6 were released yesterday (Feb 8 2022).

Comment: That's odd. It was fixed in 17.1.0 Preview 5 as well, so not sure why 17.0.6 didn't receive the same treatment.

Comment: That's a good question. If I diff cstringt.h between versions 14.29.30133 (from 16.11.10) and 14.30.30705 (from 17.0.6) you can see the fix is missing.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed by Microsoft in 17.2 Preview 1 according to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-comparison-operators-between-LPC/1614285.